# Titanium/ Appcelerator/ Alloy: Unable to get current location despite success returning true

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I am running the following code using the iPhone 4s simulater:

```
Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
    Ti.API.log(JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

A formatted version of the output of the above gives the following information:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "type":"location",
    "error":"The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)",
    "source":{}, 
    "success":true
}
```

There seems to be quite contradictory information. It says `success` is `true` yet gives an error message.

Furthermore, according to the [Location Results Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/LocationResults), it says that if success is true, it should return a `coords` field. Yet the above does not have `coords` on it.

Please also note both of the following returns `true` so its not a permission issue:

Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled;
Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS);

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to take notes of:

1. [locationServicesEnabled property for device](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-property-locationServicesEnabled)
2. [hasLocationPermissions method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-hasLocationPermissions)

First of all, you will need to check for 1st property to make sure that the device location is on.

Then you will check for **hasLocationPermissions** because this can be true even the device location is not on, which I think is your case.

Sample code for this:

```
var authType = Ti.Geolocation. AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS;

if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
    if (Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(authType)) {
        // voila...
    } else {
        Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(authType, function (e) {
            if (e.success) {
                alert('voila...');
            }
        });
    }

} else {
   alert('Please turn on your device's location');
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question and it shows that `locationServicesEnabled` is true as well. It also does not deal with the fact that `e.success` is `true` yet it gives an error message. This is against what it says on the docs.